# trouble loading google map from a list of address

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-geocoder

I have a problem and I really tried everything!

I have a page in my website that loads a google map taking a list of address from a mysql database. It was working but somehow now it's not working anymore.

Here's the script that loads the map:

```
<div id="map-canvas"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function initMap() {

    var centro = new google.maps.LatLng(45.701116, 9.665754);

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 15,
        center: centro
    }


    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);


    var contentString0 = '<div class="title">you are here!<div id="bodyContent"></div>';

    //recupero 
    <?php for($i = 0; $i < count($indirizzi); $i++) { ?>

        var contentString = '<div class="title">'<?php $nome_shop = str_replace(" ", "+",
                    $nomi[$i]); ?> + '<a href=kiwishop.php?shop=<?= $nome_shop ?>>
          <?= $nomi[$i] ?></a></div><div class="address"><?= $sottotitoli[$i] ?></div>';

        var infowindow<?= $i ?> = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: contentString
        });
        var location = "<?= $indirizzi[$i] ?>";
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    //convert location into longitude and latitude
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': location}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == 'OK') {
                var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                var lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            }                
            var marker<?= $i ?> = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: {lat: lat, lng: lng},
                title: '<?= $nomi[$i] ?>',
                icon: '<?= $iconemappa[$i] ?>'
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker<?= $i ?>, 'click', function() {
                <?php for($j = 0; $j < count($indirizzi); $j++) { ?>
                infowindow<?= $j ?>.close();
                //not working
                <?php } ?>
                infowindow<?= $i ?>.open(map,marker<?= $i ?>);
            });
        });

    <?php } ?>
}
```

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AGzaNyBMYf1ZkLWd7VGH4q_I5eF92JK6cdfcFCs&callback=initMap"></script>
```

The variables $indirizzi (addresses) , $nomi, etc.. are previously retrived from the database and I used the htmlentities() function on them.
I think the problem comes from special chars, like è or ', beacuse when I had fewer line in the database the map was working.
I get an Unespected identifier error.. and then initMap is not a function

UPDATE:

I fixed the single quote problem in the addresses. Now the map loads but only the first eleven markers.
Here's the rendered code for the last marker loaded (marker10) e the first not loaded (marker11)

```
var contentString = '<div class="title">' + '<a href=kiwishop.php?shop=Artisan+Cafè>Artisan Cafè</a></div><div class="address">Cocktail esplosivi e tapas deliziose</div>';

        var infowindow10 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: contentString
        });
        var location = "Via San Bernardino 53, Bergamo";
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    //convert location into longitude and latitude
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': location}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == 'OK') {
                var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                var lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            }                
            var marker10 = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: {lat: lat, lng: lng},
                title: 'Artisan Cafè',
                icon: '../images/icons/borgo-drink.png'
            });
});

var contentString = '<div class="title">' + '<a href=kiwishop.php?shop=Atelier+di+Rita+Patelli>Atelier di Rita Patelli</a></div><div class="address">Composizioni e creazioni con materiali naturali</div>';

        var infowindow11 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: contentString
        });
        var location = "Via Borgo Canale 9b, Bergamo";
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    //convert location into longitude and latitude
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': location}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == 'OK') {
                var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                var lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            }                
            var marker11 = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: {lat: lat, lng: lng},
                title: 'Atelier di Rita Patelli',
                icon: '../images/icons/borgo-artigiani.png'
            });
            });
```

I get this error: " InvalidValueError: setPosition: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number"  for all the remained address in the database.

So I guess the geocoder doesn't like the addresses? But they are correct!
I printed with console.log() all the variables location and they are fine (I can see all of them). I printed the status variable before the if statement and I get only 11 OK. The code to generate the marker is correct beacuse if I create a map with only the marker11 it works.. But somehow the map stops loading markers at some point.

Any ideas?

Thanks again!

Comment: Seeing the actual rendered source might help. Specifically the address marker stuff. It's probably like you describe. Viewing source in browser you might even see it, bad semi colon, unclosed quote, similar...

Comment: That code is totally unreadable and nobody can tell you what your PHP outputs in the middle of your JS. Look at your javascript console and use it to debug your code. Replace each PHP variable by hardcoded values then add them back, one after each other to see where and when it fails.

Comment: Sorry! I'm a beginner and I'm not really confident with javascript. And ok, now I'm looking at th rendered source (on the Chrome console) and I realized that the problem comes from the single quote in the php variabiles. I thought that use htmlentities() would be enough, but probably it's not the right way to fix the problem

Comment: I updated the question!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. It was caused by google maps limitations